# VLookup multiple Results on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Im Trying to Filter a list with Listitems and their Properties in Google Sheets. For that I normally use Vlookup. Now I know that Vlookup only shows the first result, is there a way to find multiples and combine them into a comma seperated list?

Heres an Example:
[image]

Comment: why did you mention excel?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=textjoin(", ",,filter(B:B,A:A="China"))
```

[image]